# How do i create dependency between two windows services running on separate machines

Tags: c#, windows-services

How do i create dependency between two Windows Services created by me but installed on separate machines. ServiceA is installed on SystemA and ServiceB is installed on SystemB.

I want to make sure that if ServiceA is running then only ServiceB should start.

I know its easy to do if they both are on same machine but since they are on different machines, i am kind of stuck here.

Comment: Are dependencies round - if ServiceB died, should ServiceA die?

Comment: No. They are not round. That will cause circular dependency.

Comment: Write a ServiceX for ServiceB machine which will be ServiceB's dependency - for pinging ServiceA over network. This will result in undefined behavior if ServiceA starts too late.

Comment: If i could do that, i would have used AngryHacker's solution. I cant expose any API in ServiceA. It just listems on a port waiting for a message and does some processing and publishes it back on some other port where ServiceB is listening.

Comment: you don't have to modify ServiceA. It was supposed to write another service and add dependency on it via registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply calling out to serviceB via TCP or Remoting or WCF?  If the service does not respond, you end serviceA.  And vice versa.

This method would work whether you are on the same machine or across the globe.

Comment: You are right. I should do that but i cant expose any APIs in ServiceA.

Comment: @Asdfg Per your comment on the original question, you already have a port that listens to commands.  One of these commands should be AreYouAlive.  When you get it respond to it - ServiceB should then act accordingly and start itself up.

Comment: It is not commands that are sent on port. Think of it as a custom MSMQ system. It piles up the messages sent on the port ServiceA is listening if ServiceA is down. The moment ServiceA is up and runnng, it subscribes to that custom MSMQ system and that custom MSMQ system sends messages to ServiceA one by one. The only way of doing is expose it on WCF and call AreYouAlive.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of options.  I'd open a TCP listener for just this one command and be done with it.

Comment: @AngryHacker - i tried tcp.connect ("wcfservername", portnumber) thinking i should get an exception since wcf is already running there but even though wcf is hosted there, i am still able to connect. isnt it suppose to throw error saying "port already in use"?

Comment: never mind. i ended up using IPGlobalProperties to see if the port is already in use or not. Great solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this.   The dependency list is buried in the registry as a list of null-delimited strings referring to a local service name.  The local service names are only allowed to point to local service EXEs or DLLs so I'm pretty sure this is not possible using the service-dependency framework in the service manager.